# Enqueue script not working

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

This is my code to enqueue scripts. The later one with title `yourscript2` is working, but the first one with title `upload` is not working:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'upload', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/upload.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'yourscript2',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/text.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at page source and verified that the script tag is not present? Is the filename and path correct? I also suggest using a handle more unique than `upload`.

Comment: When I test this, it works insofar as the appropriate markup is inserted into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `upload.js` is not being added because there is already an script added by [wordpress as default](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) for the handler `upload`.

So **I suggest you to change the handler**. If not, you can [de-register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) the upload handler registered by wordpress

```
wp_deregister_script( 'upload' );
```

and then register yours as usual. But I highly recommend you to not `de-register` defaults function(which will lead to lot of conflict in upload of wordpress), so instead **just change your handler**.

@s_ha_dum the `upload` is inserting for you because the `upload` handler is not in latest wordpress versions. [List of scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Handles_and_Their_Script_Paths_Registered_by_WordPress) registered by wordpress as of v3.8. So `Usman Ahmed Mani` might be using an old version of wordpress which has that `upload` handler